# Getting the Ubuntu to work right in VirtualBox

Tags: drivers, vdi

In VirtualBox, I was able to create a CentOS machine, but when I tried to create an Ubuntu machine and it came to the part where I designate space for it, CentOS was the only choice it gave me, even *after* I downloaded Ubuntu 17. There was no Ubuntu equivalent to the Centos .vdi file.

The machine seemed to know what Ubuntu was and let me choose it, but I couldn't load the drivers, or whatever they're called, for Ubuntu, so it was Ubuntu in name only. The VM looked and acted like CentOS.

Comment: Sounds like you told the machine to use the existing centos vdi. When you create a new machine, you create a new virtual hard disk for it as well. On the screen where centos "was the only option", there should be an option to create a new virtual disk. New machine - new vdi.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you're choosing Linux/Ubuntu on this screen. Make sure which version (32-bit/64-bit) of .iso you downloaded. Mount this .iso on the VB CD/DVD drive.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're expecting VirtualBox to install Ubuntu for you, it does not. You need to download either an existing VirtualBox virtual hard drive with Ubuntu installed on it (see here: http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/bionic/current/ for official ones provided by Canonical). Otherwise, you have to install it yourself using an ISO.